# How to change the google map marker in my website

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

How to change the google map marker and add two marker in my website.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
function init_map(lat,lng,ZmLevel) {
   var myOptions = {
      zoom:ZmLevel,center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);        
   <?php 
      $sql = "select * from locator_areas where cid=$city";
      $res = mysql_query($sql);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   ?>
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude']; ?>,<?php echo $row['longitude']; ?>)});

         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'<div style="color:#000000;"><?php echo str_replace("\'","`",$row['address']); ?></div>'
         });

         bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow);

   <?php }?>
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
   });
}

function loadCity() {
   var cid = $('#city_name').val();
   window.location = "?cid="+cid;
}
```

I want to change the marker and want to add one more marker for some new opening outlet of the company

Comment: see : [google Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons)

Comment: Can any one help please!....

Comment: How do you indicate the different markers in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify such an icon, set the marker's icon property to the URL of an image. The Google Maps API will size the icon automatically.

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$row['latitude']?>,<?=$row['longitude']?>), 
                icon: imageURL

 });
```

Please read [this article](http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/) to add multiple markers

Comment: Thank You Soo much. It worked, but I am still unable to add multiple icon. Basically what I want to do is, I have some store already opened and some has to be opened. For the open and opening in future store I want to use two different icon. You you please explain it with the above code please.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the image of the `marker` you can pass `icon` property to the `Marker` contractor. Of course, if you want to create a `markers` "groups", just set the all group's markers the same image.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
  });

  var pos = [
    {
      location: {lat: -25.463882, lng: 120.047922},
      image: 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/32/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Pink.png'
    },
    {
      location: {lat: -25.763882, lng: 130.844992},
      image: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png'
    }
  ];

  for (var i in pos) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos[i].location,
      icon: pos[i].image,
      map: map
    });  
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&signed_in=true" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Dear Mosh Feu! I want to use two different images for two different location. How to do this